# How to terminate a process with a ZeroMQ socket that has been closed?

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I'm making a publish subscribe using ZeroMQ. Here is a simplified code :

```
import zmq from 'zeromq';
import d from 'debug';

const debug = d('publisher');

let port = '8000';
let subject = 'FLIGHTS';

const socket = zmq.socket('pub');

socket.on('close', function(...toto) {
  debug('connection closed');
});
socket.on('close_error', function(...toto) {
  debug('error while closing connexion');
});

socket.monitor(10, 0);
socket.bindSync('tcp://*:' + port);

export function send(message: object) {
  const jsonMessage = JSON.stringify(message);
  socket.send([subject, jsonMessage]);
}

export function close() {
  socket.close();
}

setTimeout( () => close(), 3000 );
```

The problem I have is that the process won't exit even if the socket is closed after 3 seconds. I can't use `process.exit` because the module I'm making is used in a lot a jest tests.
I didn't find anything in the [ZeroMQ documentation](http://zeromq.github.io/zeromq.js/).

Answer (score 5):

Given the default ZeroMQ API specifications, any attempts to **`.close()`** a socket instance is blocking until a certain amount of time expires.

Typical graceful termination sequence relies on a practice of pre-setting this instance attribute right upon its creation:

```
socket.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 ); // A SYSTEMATIC STEP UPON CREATION
```

> **`ZMQ_LINGER`**: Set linger period for socket shutdown
>   The `ZMQ_LINGER` option shall set the linger period for the specified socket. The linger period determines how long pending messages which have yet to be sent to a peer shall linger in memory after a socket is disconnected with `zmq_disconnect()` or closed with `zmq_close()`, and further affects the termination of the socket's context with `zmq_ctx_term()`. The following outlines the different behaviours:
>   - A value of **-1** specifies an **infinite** linger period. Pending messages shall not be discarded after a call to `zmq_disconnect()` or `zmq_close()`;  attempting to terminate the socket's context with `zmq_ctx_term()` shall block until all pending messages have been sent to a peer.
> - 
>   The value of **0** specifies no linger period. Pending messages shall be discarded immediately after a call to `zmq_disconnect()` or `zmq_close()`.
>   - Positive values specify an upper bound for the linger period in milliseconds. Pending messages shall not be discarded after a call to `zmq_disconnect()` or `zmq_close()`; attempting to terminate the socket's context with `zmq_ctx_term()` shall block until either all pending messages have been sent to a peer, or the linger period expires, after which any pending messages shall be discarded.
>   
>   Default value ~ 30000 [ms] ( for all socket types )

For respective details, kindly read the ZeroMQ API documentation.